# Data from fixture file cannot be extracted

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to get data from a json file to use in my test, but it always gives me an error saying it can't be fetched. I checked a lot of things on the internet, a lot of videos, personally I can't find my problem.

- Cypress version 13.06

fixture file call "userData.json":

```
{
  "userName": "John"
}
```

describe block:

```
describe("Cypress Test", () => {
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.fixture("userData").then((userData) => {
      this.data = userData;
      cy.visit("WEBSITE");
    });
  });
```

My test:

```
 it("Handling FIXTURE", () => {
   cy.get('input[name="name"]').type(this.data.userName);
  });
```

The error:

```
TypeError
cy.xpath is not a function
cypress/e2e/dropDownFeatures.cy.js:86:8
  84 | 
  85 |   it("Handling FIXTURE", () => {
> 86 |     cy.get('input[name="name"]').type(this.data.userName);
     |        ^
  87 |   });
  88 | });
  89 |
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbDkD.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh5Rr.png)

this.data.userName => to feed the data from the file to the field I use it for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to to the scope of the `this.data` variable. When using arrow functions, the `this` value is inherited from the enclosing lexical scope<sup>[***1***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)</sup>. You can convert this to a regular function to fix the issue. Something like:

```js
// ...Rest

  it("Handling FIXTURE", function () { // <---- a regular function
    cy.get('input[name="name"]').type(this.data.userName);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the fixture on the global scope of the test

```js
let data;

describe("Cypress Test", () => {
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.fixture("userData").then((userData) => {
      data = userData;
    });
    cy.visit("WEBSITE");
  })

 it("Handling FIXTURE", () => {
   cy.get('input[name="name"]').type(data.userName);
  });
})
```

Or read it in using `require()`

```js
const data = require('cypress/fixtures/userData.json')

describe("Cypress Test", () => {
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.visit("WEBSITE");
  })

 it("Handling FIXTURE", () => {
   cy.get('input[name="name"]').type(data.userName);
  });
})
```